# preg_match() doesn't get proper matches

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have the following code:

```
$re = '#((<\\w+(.*?)>)(.*?)(<?.*?>)?\\n?)*#m'; 
$str = '<blockquote>Morbi pulvinar turpis vitae neque convallis mattis ac at eros. Etiam interdum ornare ipsum at efficitur. Nulla sit amet magna felis. Morbi sit amet orci eros. Aenean ac risus tellus. Nam convallis ligula id interdum porta.</blockquote>
        <img class=" alignnone" src="http:" alt="" />
        <img class=" alignnone" src="http:" alt="" />
        <img class=" alignnone" src="http:" alt="" />Sed faucibus ante sed orci rhoncus, non porta erat tempus. Donec sit amet diam at felis accumsan pharetra nec eget ipsum. Curabitur in elit porttitor risus facilisis luctus elementum ut neque. Ut placerat diam magna, ac eleifend quam sodales eget. Praesent dapibus, erat at rhoncus luctus, leo eros feugiat dolor, in egestas velit quam et lacus. Morbi pulvinar turpis vitae neque convallis mattis ac at eros. Etiam interdum ornare ipsum at efficitur. Nulla sit amet magna felis. Morbi sit amet orci eros. Aenean ac risus tellus. Nam convallis ligula id interdum porta.
        <blockquote>Morbi pulvinar turpis vitae neque convallis mattis ac at eros. Etiam interdum ornare ipsum at efficitur. Nulla sit amet magna felis. Morbi sit amet orci eros. Aenean ac risus tellus. Nam convallis ligula id interdum porta.</blockquote>
        <img class=" alignnone" src="http:" alt="" />'; 

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```

I want to grab a string match from the first `<blockquote>` until the end of the third image tag just before the start of the sentence.

When I test the RegEx here https://regex101.com/r/rA2fY9/1, it pulls the right string. But when I test it on my localhost, `$matches[0]` pulls a wrong string.

What did I do wrong? Thank you in advance!

Comment: try this https://regex101.com/r/rA2fY9/3, there may be a chance of spaces at the start.

Comment: The problem may come from the newline sequence that is different between regex101 (that uses `\n`) and your original string that uses a windows format, so `\r\n`. Replace `\\n` with `\R` (that means any type of newlines). As an aside replace all the double backslashes with a single backslash and remove the m modifier. I don't know what you are trying to do, but the right way is probably to use DOMDocument (take a look on php manual).

Comment: @AvinashRaj thank you for the answer, unfortunately it still doesn't work.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte you're correct! Thank you. The problem is `\n`. When I replace it with `\R`, it works. You should post it as an answer. I'll accept it.